# Question about partial fractions and the order of two linear factors

Tags: partial-fractions

I have a question on the topic of partial fraction and decomposition. Lets say I have the integral of $\frac{1}{(x^2 - x - 2)}$. When I want to find out the A and B values, I first have to get linear or quadratic factors (in this case linear). So I get $\frac{1}{(u-2)(u+1)}$. Now my question is, is it okay if I can switch around the factors and get $\frac{1}{(u-2)(u+1)}$ instead of $(u-2)(u+1)$. Does it matter which order you put it? If so why does the order have to be in that order? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property#Commutative_operations_in_mathematics) is Commutative, hence Order is immaterial

$$\dfrac3{x^2-x-2}=\dfrac3{(x-2)(x+1)}=\dfrac{x+1-(x-2)}{(x-2)(x+1)}=?$$